# Why is the Facebook SDK for iOS throwing the "FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled" error when the user has not canceled?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

There was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593301/facebook-ios-sdk-gives-fberrorcategoryusercancelled-for-no-reason) to this one posted not so long ago but it appears that the Apple Review team had messed up in that case. I have the same problem myself in that when clicking the "Log in with Facebook" button nothing happens, and since adding the error handling code [taken from Facebook developer section](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.0) the console is logging `user cancelled login` if when someone who **has** the Facebook app on their phone already tries log in via my app.

If they have **not** got the Facebook app on their phone is uses Safari by default, and works perfectly.

Does anybody know why this might be the case? And if so a fix to allow it to work correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be an issue when using Facebook iOS SDK 3.13.1. I upgraded to 
Facebook iOS SDK 3.14.1 and this problem went away.